# Displaying calls in a list in android application

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am trying to develop an android application which would display calls in a list. I have used the broadcast receiver. By default, the PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast is delivered more than once per each incoming call. As a result I get duplicate entries of a number in the list. I just want a single entry for each call. As far as I know I have to track the state changes of the broadcasts like for example only adding an item to the list if the previous state was idle and new state is ringing. But I am not able to do so. Can anyone help me with it? Here is the code to display the list of numbers.

```
  class CallReceiver(var mainActivity: MainActivity): BroadcastReceiver(){
     val TAG=CallReceiver::class.java.simpleName
     override fun onReceive(context: Context?,intent: Intent?){
     var action=intent?.action
     val prev:String
     val state:String


    Log.i(TAG,action)
    //intent?.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
    if(intent!!.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE))
    {

        state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        Log.i(TAG,"State is: $state")


    }
    if(intent!!.hasExtra((TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER))){
        val number = 
       intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
        mainActivity.addPhoneNumberList(number)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You should use a smart implementation of the BroadcastReceiver to get a sense of what's happening on the phone state side…
Some classes already exist, [take a look at this gist](https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee) that might help you achieving what you want!

Answer (score 0):

you can remove duplicate entries using hashmap so previous entry overwrite new entry